# Passing this.props.history.push to attribute in one variable in another component. REACT JS

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I created one password form that needs pass values to one variable localized in another js.

The Scope is:

```
App.js
|
|
|----- Login.jsx
|
|
|_____ Home.jsx
         |----- import { getMarvelCharacters } from '../lib/apiCalls';
```

App.js

```
const Home = lazy(() => import('./Components/Home'));
const Login = lazy(() => import('./Components/Login'));

const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Login}/>
        <Route path="/home" component={Home}/>
      </Switch>
    </Suspense>
  </Router>
);
```

Login.jsx

```
    handleSubmit = event => {
    //The alert show both value ok..
        alert('publickey is: ' + this.state.publickey + ' and privatekey is: ' + this.state.privatekey);
        event.preventDefault();
        try {
            this.props.history.push({
                pathname: '/home',
                state: {
                    publickey: this.state.publickey,
                    privatekey: this.state.privatekey,
                }
            })
        } catch (e) {
            alert(e.message);
        }
    }
```

But I need take this values e put in apiCalls.js

```
const PUBLIC_KEY = " here ";
const PRIVATE_KEY = " here ";
```

Please, what's the best way to make it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Redux to push the data from your login component to the redux store and use it in another component inside of the application

and if you don't want to use Redux, then you have to create the functions inside of the main root component (which is usually App.js) and pass those functions inside the child components using props, the children will propagate the values to the root component or you can create the functions inside of the children and propagate the values to the root component (depends on your use case of each component like if this function is going to be done for one component or all components)

to reuse those values, you pass the root component's state as props inside of the child

hope my answer helped a bit

Comment: Yes, I understand but both are not to easy yet :) I don't use Redux now for this exercises, in the next it sure. Thank you.

Comment: So I Still have one doubt, please. The file apiCalls.js no use import React, at this form it file doesn't exist in React lifecycle, right?

Comment: So, how can I Import the history to this?